# Fixed title changing styles on scroll

Tags: javascript

Alright, so i have a fixed banner that i would like to change background-color and font color after i start scrolling. Would be amazing if it changes back to transparent after im on top. I figured to make two different classes, 1 for top and 1 for when scrolling, problem is i cant make jscript add the scrolling class.

```
$(window).addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 50){
        $(".banner-top").addClass("banner-top-active");
    }else{
        $(".banner-top").removeClass("banner-top-active");
    }
});
```

This is what i tried this far

```html
<div class="banner-top">
    <h1 id="top">Lalala</h1>
    <img class="menu-icon" src="assets/icons/menu-icon-white.svg">
</div>
```

```css
.banner-top{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.banner-top-active{
    background-color: white;
}
```

Was expecting it to work of course but nothing at all happens. I might be targeting the window variable wrongly. Im not quite sure, but while inspecting, nothing was happening what so ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give an id to your div, like so:

```
<div id="banner" class="banner-top">
    <img class="menu-icon" src="assets/icons/menu-icon-white.svg">
</div>
```

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {  
  const banner = document.getElementById("banner");
    if(window.scrollY > 50) {
      banner.classList.add("banner-top-active");        
    } else{
      banner.classList.remove("banner-top-active");        
    }
});
```

and for the transparency, you can use opacity property in your banner-top-active class, eg opacity: 0.8;

Comment: Seems that scrollY did the trick, do you mind explaining to me quickly why? why didnt the scrollTop() work?

Answer (score 1):

You want to add the event listener to the `window` object directly, like this:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 50){
        $(".banner-top").addClass("banner-top-active");
    }else{
        $(".banner-top").removeClass("banner-top-active");
    }
});
```

CodeSandBox example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-surf-0z2m5?fontsize=14